# jQuery slide/toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Newbie in JS / jQuery here.
First problem: When page is loading or it is refreshing whole sub-sub menus are blinked for like 0.5sec so they can "hide". I have put the script firstly on the end of "body" tag, but after this blink I've put it in "head" so is there any way to make it actually hide, like really hide, to not be shown when page is on load?
Second problem is when I'm clicking on either blue or green square menu is not sliding smoothly. It's like a bounce effect. Is it because of "hide"? And last problem is with slideDown function. Where shall I use slideUp to make it go back to the position where it hides?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
 $(".raid ul").hide();
    $(".raid").hide();
    
    $(".wod").one("click", function() 
 {
        $(".wod ul li").slideDown(200);
    });
    
    $(".mop").one("click", function() 
 {
        $(".mop ul li").slideDown(200);
    });
    
    $(".hfc").click(function() 
 {
        $(".hfc").addClass('x');
        $(".hfc ul").slideToggle(200);
    });
    $(".soo").click(function() 
 {
        $(".soo ul").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```css
ul 
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#progress
{
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1
{
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #00c99a;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.expansion
{
    text-align-last: center;
    width: inherit;
    height: 108px;
   
}

.expansion:first-child
{
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.mop, .wod
{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

.wod > ul
{
 margin-top: 90px;   
}

.mop > ul
{
 margin-top: 90px;   
}

.wod
{
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}

.mop
{

    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    background-color: green;
}

.raid > ul
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 20px;  
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.nhm
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 20px 1px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: default;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.hfc-progress, .soo-progress,
{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: default;
    color: white;
}

.hfc, .soo
{
    color: limegreen;
    background-color: rgba(37, 65, 23, 0.5);
}

.hfc:hover, .soo:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: greenyellow;
}

.x
{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress"><h1>Progress</h1>
                <div id="expansion">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="expansion wod"><br />
                            <ul>
                                <li class="raid hfc"><h3>Hellfire Citadel ↓</h3>    
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="hfc-progress">Hellfire Assault
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="nhm hfcn">N</li>
                                                <li class="nhm hfch">H</li>
                                                <li class="nhm hfcm">M</li>
                                            </ul> 
                                          </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                      
                        <li class="expansion mop"><br />
                        <ul>
                                <li class="raid soo"><h3>Siege of Orgrimmar↓</h3>    
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="soo-progress">Immerseus
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="nhm soon">N</li>
                                                <li class="nhm sooh">H</li>
                                                <li class="nhm soom">M</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                          
                        </ul>
                   </li>
              </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Too much code, you should to leave only important part.

Comment: Aight, I've sorted a bit this chaotic code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the elements hidden, use CSS. The CSS can have properties like

```
.raid ul { 
   display: none;
} 
.raid {
   display: none;
}
```

instead of calling the `hide()` function in jQuery. This way, if you include the CSS in the head section and keep your JS in the bottom, the blink would not happen (because the browser would keep them hidden by default)